# ¿Disminuir un campo en MySQL todos los días?

Tags: php, python, laravel, laravel-5, web

Lo que necesito es disminuir un valor que esta almacenado en una base de datos.

Es decir tengo la tabla con nombre **solicitudes** la cual tiene un campo que se llamada **diasconsumidos** en esta tabla existen muchos registros y el campo **diascosumidos** se almacena un int.

Lo que debe hacer la pagina web es todos los dias estar diminuyendo el valor del campo de **diasconsumidos** de todos los registros que se encuentra en la tabla solicitudes.

He estado pensando en crearme un script en python o php que haga este trabajo pero quiero saber si existe la forma de que el propio mysql lo pueda hacer o otras opciones.

Cabe mencionar que me encuentro en LARAVEL.

Comment: Podrías hacer un stored procedure en mysql

Comment: Precisamente estaba documentandome acerca de ello pero aun estoy buscando como hacerlo para que se ejecute automáticamente todos los dias

Comment: Mira estos links... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704547/how-to-schedule-an-automatic-call-to-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql-every-hour-betw

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64208/scheduling-an-event-every-day-at-a-given-time

Comment: Dado que requieres ejecutar el código periódicamente tal vez te podría valer implementar un [Scheduled Event](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Answer (score 1):

En MySQL existe el planificador de eventos (Event Scheduler) que te permite programar la ejecución de comandos SQL periódicamente, similar al `cron` pero dentro del mismo MySQL.

Para saber si está habilitado el planificador puedes revisar el valor de la variable de sistema `event_scheduler` con:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE `event_scheduler%`;
```

o

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler;
```

- Si el valor es `ON` el planificador está habilitado y activo.
- Si el valor es `OFF` el planificador está habilitado, pero está inactivo.  Se puede activar cambiando el valor de la variable global a `ON`: `SET @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler = 1;`, siempre y cuando tengas los privilegios necesarios.
- Si el valor es `DISABLED` el planificador no está habilitado y no se puede activar.

En caso de que esté activado el planificador, puedes crear un evento que se ejecute todos los días a partir de las cero horas del 6 de abril del 2017 de la siguiente manera:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `MiEvento`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-05-06 00:00:00'
COMMENT 'La descripción de mi evento'
DO
BEGIN
    -- El código que se quiere ejecutar
    update `solicitudes` set
        `diasconsumidos` = `diasconsumidos` - 1
    where
        `diasconsumidos` > 0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Es importante mencionar que en la configuración de arranque de MySQL se debe habilitar el planificador (con la directiva `event_scheduler=1` en `my.cnf`), ya que el planificador está deshabilitado por omisión.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, no sería mas fácil...

En vez de actualizar tu registro todos los días, puedes agregar un campo de fecha llamado (por ejemplo) `ultima_actualizacion`. La idea es que no tengas una tarea que lo haga cada día, sino que cada vez que consultes o accedas a ese datos, calcules los días transcurridos desde la ultima actualización y lo vuelvas a actualizar.

Entonces en tu migración agregas:

```
$table->date('updated_at');
```

En en código iría algo así:

```
public function getSolicitud (Request $request){
    $solicitud = Solicitud::select('*', 'datediff(now(), solicitud.updated_at) as diferencia')
        ->where('id', $request->input('id'));

    $solicitud->diascosumidos += $solicitud->diferencia;
    // hacer otras operaciones

    return response()->json(array('completed' => $solicitud->save());
}
```

Ahora si quieres modificar todos los campos de la tabla por sql puedes usar algo como:

```sql
UPDATE solicitud SET diasconsumidos = diasconsumidos + datediff(now(), solicitud.updated_at);
```

Comment: Bueno ya había pensado en eso pero no aplica en mi caso ya que se ofrece un servicio y esto tiene que ejecutarse asi no se ingrese a la pagina. entonces investigando sera necesario utilizar con laravel Commands y Schedule

Comment: @FuriosoJack Cuando intente ingresar lo validas como está en este ejemplo, no veo cual es el problema. Si `$solicitud->diascosumidos` despues de la actualización es mayor que el limite, simplemente lo rediriges a la página que quieres, mostrandole que los días se han acabado. De hecho podrías hacerlo con un [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware), entonces lo filtras en las [rutas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware). Si explicas tu caso completo en la pregunta podrían ayudarte mas :P